# jquery append truncate

Tags: jquery

I have a selectlist box in Jquery
I am doing something like:

```
      $("#Deg").append(degtems);
```

As I am calling the above code a number of times, it keeps on appending.
How do I trunctate and then append.

Thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) first:

```
$("#Deg").empty().append(degtems);
```

..or you could simply use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) as [@KevinB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400654/kevin-b) points out below:

```
$("#Deg").html(degtems);
```

Comment: Or, you can use `.html()` which calls `.empty()` and `.append()` for the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

Try using .html:

```
$("#Deg").html(degtems);
```

It's essentially just doing this:

```
$("#Deg").empty().append(degtems);
```

- http://api.jquery.com/html
- http://api.jquery.com/empty

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.empty` method on the select element first to remove all children:

```
$("#Deg").empty()

....
$("#Deg").append(degtems);
```